# Using splice in javascript remove all elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I m trying to remove a specific element from my array with a string index
but all my elements are removed

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray['abc'] = 'abc';
myArray['cde'] = 'cde';
myArray['efg'] = 'efg';

console.log('before splice:');
console.log(myArray);

myArray = myArray.splice('abc',1);
console.log('after splice:');
console.log(myArray);


before splice:
[abc: "abc", cde: "cde", efg: "efg"]
after splice:
[]
```

doc found on this link [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

doesn't explicit say if index must be an integer or anything else

Comment: Arrays can't have string keys!

Comment: @Louy: Yes they can. They can't have string *indexes*, however.

Comment: Yeah, I guess "key" is an object term.

Comment: So many answers already, I'm just wondering though, why the need to mix object property with array?  I haven't had the need to mix array with object in my experience.

Comment: @Will Because of my misunderstanding about objects and arrays. 
but now it's clear for me.

Comment: splice() is not like slice() which doesn't modify the original array. splice() modifies the array, and returns the deleted elements, that's why you have an empty array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want here is not Arrays but Objects.

```
var myObj = {};

myObj['abc'] = 'abc';
myObj['cde'] = 'cde';
myObj['efg'] = 'efg';

// and you can then

delete myObj['abc'];
```

Arrays can only have integer indexes.

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = 'abc';
myArray[1] = 'cde';
myArray[2] = 'efg';

console.log('before splice:');
console.log(myArray);

myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf('abc'),1);
console.log('after splice:');
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript `Array` being a JavaScript object can have arbitrary attributes.  What you are doing in your code is setting 3 attributes, and not pushing elements to array.

```
console.log('before splice:');
console.log(myArray);
#=> [ abc: 'abc', cde: 'cde', efg: 'efg' ]
console.log(myArray.length);
#=> 0
```

The attributes are not present when you print the `myArray` after `splice` as `splice` returns a new `Array` composed of deleted elements, which in this case happens to be an empty array `[]` as no elements were deleted

Answer (score 3):

To all of you who came here looking for **how to actually remove all the members from an array with splice**, the simple answer is:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.splice(0); //[1,2,3,4] 
// arr = []
```

`splice(startPosition, pcsToRemove)`

The first 0 tells splice to start from the very beginning of the array.

*Not setting the second parameter will make it default to splice the whole array.*

Not answering the authors question here, just answering the title:

> Using splice in javascript remove all elements from array

Answer (score 2):

Use `delete obj[key]` to delete a key value pair from an object. `Splice` is use in case of `arrays` and in case of `object` use `delete`.

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray['abc'] = 'abc';
myArray['cde'] = 'cde';
myArray['efg'] = 'efg';

delete myArray.abc;
// or,
delete myArray['abc'];
```

Comment: I think you were using `myJsonObject`.

Comment: That was a typo, not a wrong answer, probably while typing i thought the wrong variable, in this case you should mention it in the comment instead of downvoting the answer. My thought.

Comment: Alright. I removed the vote anyway after you corrected it. I think you're right.

Comment: Not *object literals*, just *objects*.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the incorrect `splice` syntax, you're trying to use an array when the data structure is an object.

```
var obj = {};

obj['abc'] = 'abc';
obj['cde'] = 'cde';
obj['efg'] = 'efg';
```

You can then delete the property straight off the object:

```
var keyToDelete = 'abc';
delete obj[keyToDelete];
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/8a1a7e3k/)

If you *had* an array:

```
var arr = ['abc', 'cde', 'efg'];
```

Then you *could* use splice, for example in an iteration of the array:

```
var elToDelete = 'cde';
for (var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i] === elToDelete) {
     arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Or you could use `filter` to return a new array that doesn't contain that element:

```
var elToDelete = 'cde';
arr = arr.filter(function (el) {
  return el !== elToDelete;
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/hw0naapg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray['abc'] = 'abc';
```

It doesn't push item to your array. You just created javascript object to your array. In consequences you can't slice you array.

Put myArray to you webbrowser console. You will see that array is empty.